# Having issues with typescript in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am having issues with typescript react in when try to define a value.

Here is the error:

> Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type
> 'SetStateAction<boolean[]>'.   Type '{}' is not assignable to type
> '(prevState: boolean[]) => boolean[]'.
> Type '{}' provides no match for the signature '(prevState: boolean[]): boolean[]'.ts(2345)

Here is my following code:

```
const [addButtonFruits, setAddButtonFruits] = useState([true]);

useEffect(() => {
    const initialAddButtonFruits = {};
    fruitsArray.map((each) => (initialAddButtonFruits[each] = true));
    setAddButtonFruits(initialAddButtonFruits);
  }, []); // only executed for initial rendering
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error message says exactly what is wrong. Your state variable `addButtonFruits` is a boolean array. And you are trying to assign an object to it.

Try:

```
    const initialAddButtonFruits = fruitsArray.map(each => true);
    setAddButtonFruits(initialAddButtonFruits);
```

If you want to store an object:

```
const [addButtonFruits, setAddButtonFruits] = useState({});

useEffect(() => {
    const initialAddButtonFruits = {};
    fruitsArray.forEach((each) => (initialAddButtonFruits[each] = true));
    setAddButtonFruits(initialAddButtonFruits);
  }, []); // only executed for initial rendering
```

Answer (score 0):

addButtonFruits is a boolean array.
You can't assign an empty object to a boolean array variable.

```
const initialAddButtonFruits = [];
```